# 15.04 liveusb "install ubuntu" app wont work

Tags: boot, 15.04, live-usb

I have a new Asus computer with plenty of space and ram, Intel i7, and GTX 950 m, and am trying to install Ubuntu via a live boot. I use try Ubuntu and it boots, but when i try to open the install Ubuntu 15.04 app, it never loads. all other programs seem to work. using the install Ubuntu option when booting it puts up the Ubuntu logo and the loading dots but the dots stop and it never loads. how do I get it to install?

I tried running the program ubiquity.desktop from the terminal and got the following :

```
./ubiquity.desktop: line 1: [Desktop: command not found
...
./ubiquity.desktop: line 98: di: command not found
./ubiquity.desktop: line 99: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ubiquity.desktop: line 99: `Comment[lt]=Įdiegti Linux operacinę sistemą į kompiuterio (standųjį) diską'
```

Answer (score 0):

check your cd  image or iso file. or re-download it from ubuntu official website.
make bootable cd or pendrive. [help](http://pendrivelinux.com)

try boot from cd or pendrive and use try ubuntu.
after successfully loaded you will found install ubuntu option on the desktop or left sidebar.
try to install.